# The behavior of /g mode matching

Tags: javascript, regex

On [this article](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1214/javascript-regular-expression-enlightenment), it mentioned

> Make sure you are clear on the fact that an expression pattern is
>   tested on each individual character. And that, just because the engine
>   moves forward when following the pattern and looking for a match it
>   still backtracks and examines each character in a string until a match
>   is found or if the global flag is set until all characters are
>   examined.

But what I tested in Javascript

```
"aaa@bbb".match(/a+@b+/g)
```

does not produce a result like:

```
["aaa@bbb", "aa@bbb", "a@bbb"]
```

It only produces `["aaa@bbb"]`. It seems it does not examine each character to test the pattern. Can anyone can explain a little on matching steps ？ Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`/g` does not mean it will try to find every *possible* subset of characters in the input string which may match the given pattern. It means that once a match is found, it will continue searching for more substrings which may match the pattern starting from the previous match onward.

For example:

```
"aaa@bbb ... aaaa@bbbb".match(/a+@b+/g);
```

Will produce

```
["aaa@bbb", "aaaa@bbbb"]
```

Comment: `a+@b+` will not match `ccc@ddd`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Until and unless ,the beginning of `...` contains  is not `b` or ending is not `a`. :)

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT I don't understand your comment.

Comment: ok, thanks, so the sample in article is wrong, as it mentioned: "
The match would be "A1". Normally the engine would be done, but the /g flag was set so the engine will continue to the end of the string checking each character in the string regardless of how many matches it finds. Now, the engine backtracks to the "1" character and repeats the expression logic "

Comment: and so we can say not every single character will be tested as the starting point for a regxp

Comment: @caesarwang Well it's not wrong, but it may be poorly worded. "*it still backtracks and examines each character in a string until a match is found or if the global flag is set until all characters are examined.*" -- It doesn't backtrack after a match is found and tries to another match within the same set of characters. It continues forward from the point where the previous match was found.

Comment: @p.s.w.g No its a part of fun, say if `...` is `bwerera` then `"aaa@bbb ... aaaa@bbbb".match(/a+@b+/g);` will not produce `["aaa@bbb", "aaaa@bbbb"]`., rather it will produce `["aaa@bbbb", "aaaaa@bbbb"]`

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT Okay, well I meant that if you use the exact string from my example (with three literal `.` characters) that's the result you'd get. I didn't mean to imply that could you could substitute absolutely anything for `...` and get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

That explanation is mixing two distinct concepts that IMO should be kept separated

### A) backtracking

When looking for a match the normal behavior for a quantifier (`?`, `*`, `+`) is to be "greedy", i.e. to munch as much as possible... for example in `/(a+)([^b]+)/` tested with `aaaacccc` all the `a` will be part of group 1 even if of course they also match the char set `[^b]` (everything but `b`).

However if grabbing too much is going to prevent a match the RE rules require that the quantifier "backtracks" capturing less if this allows the expression to match. For example in `(a+)([^b]+)` tested with `aaaa` the group 1 will get only three `a`s, to leave one for group 2 to match.

You can change this greedy behavior with "non-greedy quantifiers" like `*?`, `+?`, `??`. In this case stills the engine does backtracking but with the reverse meaning: a non-greedy subexpression will eat as little as possible **that allows the rest of expression to match**. For example `(a+)(a+b+)` tested with `aaabbb` will leave two `a`s for group 1 and `abbb` for group 2, but `(a+?)(a+b+)` with the same string instead will leave only one `a` for group 1 because this is the minimum that allows matching the remaining part.

Note that also because of backtracking the greedy/non-greedy options doesn't change if an expression has a match or not, but only how big is the match and how much goes to each sub-expression.

### B) the "global" option

This is something totally unrelated to backtracking and simply means that instead of stopping at the first match the search must find all **non-overlapping** matches. This is done by finding the first match and then starting again the search **after the end of the match**.

Note that each match is computed using the standard regexp rules and there is no look-ahead or backtracking between different matches: in other words if making for example a greedy match shorter would give more matches in the string this option is not considered... `a+[^b]+` tested with `aaaaaa` is going to give only one match even if `g` option is specified and even if the substrings `aa`, `aa`, `aa` would have been each a valid match for the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

When the global flag is used, it starts searching for the next match after the end of the previous match, to prevent generating lots of overlapping matches like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify `/g`, the engine will stop as soon as a match is found.

If you do specify `/g`, it will keep going after a match. It will, however, still not produce *overlapping* matches, which is what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Its because.,

**What Regex try to do:**
All regex expression will try to match the `best match.`

**What Regex wont do**
It will not match the combinations for a single match as in your case.

**When your `"aaa@bbb".match(/a+@b+/g)` scenario works**

Rather, `aaa@bbbHiaa@bbbHelloa@bbbSEEYOU` try for some thing like this, which will give you

```
aaa@bbb
aa@bbb
a@bbb
```